# Shutdown stderr and redirect message to stdout

Tags: bash, shell, tcl, stdout, stderr

I am using TCL-Expect and I'm executing a script within a script. Is it possible to shutdown the stderr stream and write all other messages to stdout?

```
    set runcmd [ exec $SCRIPTS_PATH/config $build_tag -u 2>&- >&stdout]

    # Just in case...
    if { [catch $runcmd res] } {
       send_user "Failed to run command due to: $res"
    }
```

The current behavior of the code above will not display anything to stdout, but stderrs are avoided and also not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tcl (and expect) `exec` command *defines its own redirections*: see http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/exec.htm -- you can't just assume sh/bash redirections will work.

You want

```
if { [catch {exec $SCRIPTS_PATH/config $build_tag -u 2>/dev/null} res] != 0 } {
   send_user "Failed to run command due to: $res"
}
```

If you want to send stderr to stdout, use `2>@1` (see the man page)

If you want to declare the command as a variable, do this:

```
set runcmd [list exec $SCRIPTS_PATH/config $build_tag -u 2>/dev/null]

if { [catch $runcmd res] != 0 } {
   send_user "Failed to run command due to: $res"
}
```

If you really want to use shell redirections, you have to execute the command in a shell:

```
set runcmd [list exec sh -c "$SCRIPTS_PATH/config $build_tag -u 2>&1"]
```

I don't see that `2>&-` is valid in the bash man page: `n<&-` closes file descriptor *n* though.

Comment: You'll also want to read http://wiki.tcl.tk/exec, particularly the "Child Status" section.

Answer (score 1):

To suppress stderr you can do:

```
exec config $build_tag -u 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Changing to "exec config $build_tag -u 2>&1" does not seem to dump any output of the script onto my screen :(

Comment: try `exec config $build_tag -u > build.out 2>&1` and then check build.out file

Comment: In this case, errors were redirected as expected and the output was sent to a file. But it's very important to me that users of my script see the output of the executed script scrolling across their screen (as well as myself for debugging). Do you have a suggestion to bring the output from the file to the screen?

Comment: Well by default stderr goes too terminal only. So `exec config $build_tag -u` should show both stdout and stderr data on terminal.

Comment: Sounds like it may not work in a way that I intend. I just want to stop stders from showing up on the screen. For some reason my script runs to completion, but then at the very end an error pops up killing my parent script.

Comment: Your previous suggested seems more correct. After I tried "2>/dev/null" I get the error and no stdout.

Comment: Hmm not sure this is standard way of suppressing stderr.

Answer (score 1):

If I was running a command that wanted to spew irrelevant rubbish to stderr that I wanted to suppress, I'd ditch it with `2>/dev/null`.

```
# The “list” is important! It says “build a list here” instead of direct evaluation
set runcmd [list $SCRIPTS_PATH/config $build_tag -u]
exec {*}$runcmd 2>/dev/null
```

That would still produce an error if `$SCRIPTS_PATH/config` has a non-zero exit code, but that's usually the right thing. To catch it:

```
if {[catch { exec {*}$runcmd 2>/dev/null }]} {
    # An error has been trapped
}
```

Tcl doesn't provide a way of running a subprocess with its stderr outright closed; that's a pretty strange state to be in really. Redirected to /dev/null is far more likely to be useful and sane.

On the other hand, if you were to want to run with the errors going to the outer Tcl script's stderr without causing an error if those messages are generated (a *very* irritating feature of `exec` at times) — so any error from `exec` only comes from the subprocess exit code — that's done with a different redirection, like this:

```
exec {*}$runcmd 2>@stderr
```

This is because `exec` normally traps the subprocess stderr to use as a source for better error messages. It's all made more complex by the fact that some commands use stderr to print error messages but don't actually error out correctly, yet others write logging information to stderr, and not just error messages. (It's all a bit of a swamp, and its the result of many people hacking together code over a long time. Tcl merely tries to do what it can in this space; I'm not convinced it gets it right, but past design choices are sanctified by the number of scripts that rely on them now.)

---

What I *wouldn't* do is put the `exec` or the redirection(s) in the `list` command invocation; I think that is too confusing. I prefer to keep “things that belong to Tcl” more directly expressed. This is just a matter of taste, but I think it is clearer. It also allows me to think of constructing the command and then firing it off to a subordinate shell for evaluation; the inner syntax is different (shell, not Tcl) but you can then do stuff like this:

```
set runcmd "$SCRIPTS_PATH/config $build_tag -u"
exec /bin/sh -c $runcmd 2>/dev/null
```

This is logically pretty equivalent, and better for some things.

---

If you're using 8.4 (or earlier!) still, you won't be able to use the `{*}` syntax. Provided `$runcmd` is constructed by `list`, you're fine doing this as an alternative.

```
eval exec $runcmd 2>/dev/null
```

Theoretically, you should actually write:

```
eval [list exec] [lrange $runcmd 0 end] [list 2>/dev/null]
```

But that's **awful** and the sort of thing that's only necessary when `$runcmd` might not be a canonical-format list. (We added the list-expansion syntax in 8.5 because we never wanted to see that sort of monstrosity again, and because we found that being sufficiently careful was hard in all cases, with being slapdash about it leading to bugs.)

If you're using 8.4 and aren't very strictly forced to stick with it, do upgrade to at least 8.5; 8.4 is no longer in support. (We did support it for well over a decade…) 8.5 is pretty strongly compatible with 8.4, but it's worth checking whether your code really works. It pays to be careful. If you hit a problem, ask a question on Stack Overflow about fixing it of course. For all that, my scripts all Just Worked when I migrated them so its worth a try.

Comment: So I cannot use `{*}`, so we're likely using TCL8.4. The following suggestion: `eval exec $runcmd 2>/dev/null` works, but the stdout does not display the config's script output to the screen. Not sure if you have a suggestion for that. A request to update TCL sounds like a good idea though!

Comment: Wow, we're actually using several builds tclsh, which are: 8.3.5, 8.4, 8.5. Whenever I run my code in with TCL 8.5 everything runs great! No problems with my original code at all, but when I run with any other version things go badly. So, I believe this is genuinely related to environment/version issues. Unfortunately, our large company would prefer to avoid upgrading to a new version due to breaking working scripts.

Comment: @Jake88 8.3.5? That's not been supported for many years. 8.4 is now out of support, and 8.5 is the one for ultra-conservatives. (All Tcl support tends to end up being pretty much long-term anyway; we're a bunch of pretty conservative guys who like to use it in industrial settings, so we understand the difficulty of upgrading stuff.) You might be able to hire support, but not from me; I don't take on side contracts at all.

Comment: That said, there's not much syntactic difference from 8.3 to 8.4; it's mostly a bunch of new/extended commands (and it's faster too!) 8.5 added new syntax (the ever-ugly `{*}`) and many new commands. 8.6 adds more commands and some really nifty capabilities. We've now started to work towards a 9.0 — with _some_ breakage allowed, but probably not much as we're not rewriting just for the heck of it — but that's probably not going to hit final release for quite a while yet. (The main thing being studied right now is how to compile Tcl scripts all the way to native code.)